# Spectral theorem, how to show spectral measure has no atoms

Tags: measure-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory, ergodic-theory

This is from Peter Walters' *An Introduction to Ergodic Theory*. He quotes the "Spectral Theorem for Unitary Operators" which I understand:

If $U$ is a unitary operator on a complex Hilbert space $H$, then for each $f \in H$ there is a unique finite Borel measure $\mu_f$ on the circle $K=\{|z|=1\}\subseteq \mathbb{C}$ such that
$$
\langle U^n f, f\rangle = \int_K \lambda^n \mu_f(d\lambda),\qquad \forall n \in \mathbb{Z}.
$$

But he also remarks that if $T$ is measure preserving with measure preserving inverse then $U_Tf:= f \circ T$ is a unitary operator on $L^2$.
Further (and this is the part I don't understand) if $1$ is the only eigenvalue of $U_T$ with constants the only eigenvectors and $\langle f,1\rangle = 0$, then $\mu_f$ has no atoms.
I don't see how to show this. Clearly I can take $n=0$ and the hypotheses tell me $\mu_f(K) = 0$ but I don't see much else that can be said from this. Can I construct a non-constant eigenvector if I knew $\mu_f\{x\}>0$ for some $x$?

Comment: I don't think I'll answer your question at all, but today I came across this paper and I remembered your question. Here the author proves (lemma 3) that a measure related with the transfer operator has no atoms. Maybe it is possible for you to adapt the technique used by the author to your problem. Note that he's the same author of the book you're reading:
http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01174569

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may helps you:

> **Theorem.**
>
> Let $U$ be a (linear) isometry of a separable Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$, and $H_{e}(U)$ be the closure of the subspace spanned by the eigenvectors of $U$.
>
> Then for $f \in \mathcal{H}$, $$f \perp H_{e}(U) \Rightarrow \mu_{f} \mbox{ has no atoms.}$$
>
> > **Proof.**
> >
> > Let $f \perp H_{e}(U)$ and $W = e^{-2\pi i x}U$. Then by *von Neumann ergodic theorem*, let $$g = \lim \limits _{n \rightarrow \infty} {1 \over n} \sum \limits _{k = 0} ^{n-1} W^{k}f.$$ Then $Wg = g$ so that $g$ is an eigenvector of $U$ with eigenvalue $e^{2\pi i x}$ if $g \neq 0$.
> >
> > Now we have $$\left\langle g, f \right\rangle  = \lim \limits _{n \rightarrow \infty} {1 \over n} \sum \limits _{k = 0} ^{n-1} e^{-2\pi i x k } \left\langle U^{k}f, f \right\rangle = \lim \limits _{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{0} ^{1} {1 \over n} \sum \limits _{k = 0} ^{n-1} e^{-2\pi i (x-y) k } \mu_{f}(dy) = \mu_{f}(x).$$
> >
> > Hence if $\mu_{f}(x) > 0$, then $g \in H_{e}(U)$ and $f \not\perp g$, which contradicts to the assumption $f \perp H_{e}(U)$. This completes the proof.