# If $T$ has continuous spectrum and $(f, 1)=0$ then $\mu_{f}$ has no atoms.

Tags: measure-theory, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory, ergodic-theory

I'm reading Peter Walters' *An Introduction to Ergodic Theory*, and I don't understand his remark.

Following is a sort of lemma, called *Spectral Theorem for Unitary Operators*, to prove the equivalence of weak-mixing and having continuous spectrum:

> **Theorem 1.25 (Spectral Theorem for Unitary Operators)** in above book
>
> Suppose $U$ is a unitary operator on a complex Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. Then for each $f \in \mathcal{H}$ there exists a unique finite Borel measure $\mu_{f}$ on $K = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} \ : \ |z| = 1\}$ such that
>
> $$(U^{n}f, f) = \int _{K} \lambda ^{n} d\mu_{f}(\lambda) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \forall n \in \mathbb{Z}.$$

Then he remark that:

> If $T$ is an invertible measure-preserving transformation then $U_{T}$ is unitary, and if $T$ has continuous spectrum and $(f, 1) = 0$ then $\mu_{f}$ has no atoms.

This is **what I don't understand.** How can we show that **under such conditions, $\mu_{f}$ has no atoms?**

I found a related [reference](http://u.math.biu.ac.il/%7Esolomyb/GRAD/15/ET/spectral.pdf), and here **Theorem 1.4** is related to what I want to know. And he left my question as an easy(?) exercise.

Can somebody help me please?

Comment: This is an old, unsolved problem ;) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1936120/spectral-theorem-how-to-show-spectral-measure-has-no-atoms

Comment: @mathworker21 What does "unsolved" mean? "Open problem"? or "questioned 2 years ago but there was no solution in stackexchange"?

Comment: The latter. I was just making a joke

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spectral theorem, how to show spectral measure has no atoms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1936120/spectral-theorem-how-to-show-spectral-measure-has-no-atoms)

Answer (score 2):

I wrote following for the similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2846898/575354).

It may helps you:

> **Theorem.**
>
> Let $U$ be a (linear) isometry of a separable Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$, and $H_{e}(U)$ be the closure of the subspace spanned by the eigenvectors of $U$.
>
> Then for $f \in \mathcal{H}$, $$f \perp H_{e}(U) \Rightarrow \mu_{f} \mbox{ has no atoms.}$$
>
> > **Proof.**
> >
> > Let $f \perp H_{e}(U)$ and $W = e^{-2\pi i x}U$. Then by *von Neumann ergodic theorem*, let $$g = \lim \limits _{n \rightarrow \infty} {1 \over n} \sum \limits _{k = 0} ^{n-1} W^{k}f.$$ Then $Wg = g$ so that $g$ is an eigenvector of $U$ with eigenvalue $e^{2\pi i x}$ if $g \neq 0$.
> >
> > Now we have $$\left\langle g, f \right\rangle  = \lim \limits _{n \rightarrow \infty} {1 \over n} \sum \limits _{k = 0} ^{n-1} e^{-2\pi i x k } \left\langle U^{k}f, f \right\rangle = \lim \limits _{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{0} ^{1} {1 \over n} \sum \limits _{k = 0} ^{n-1} e^{-2\pi i (x-y) k } \mu_{f}(dy) = \mu_{f}(x).$$
> >
> > Hence if $\mu_{f}(x) > 0$, then $g \in H_{e}(U)$ and $f \not\perp g$, which contradicts to the assumption $f \perp H_{e}(U)$. This completes the proof.

Comment: Very nice! I was wondering how you cook up an eigenvector - of course von Neumann's ergodic theorem is a handy tool. Should've thought of that. Have you seen this proof in any book? If so, which one?

Comment: @mathworker21 I referred to the book **Introduction to Dynamical Systems, written by Michael Brin and Garrett Stuck**! See chapter 4! I studied this field (Dynamical Systems and Ergodic Theory) with this book at first! This book is well-written and I recommend it to anybody who are interested in this field even though he or she has no experience of studying this field.